# inverted commas does not work for multiple line in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to put huge html code in jquery , using inverted
commas,but after a line break , inverted commas is not working , How
to do this ,Can anybody suggest how to do this .The html code is written append

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#addmore').click(function(){
    $('#item').append("<div class='form-group'><label class='col-sm-4 '>Period</label><div class='col-sm-8'><div class='checkbox'><label><input type='checkbox' value='YES' name='currently_attending'>I`m currently attending this course</label></div><div class='row'><div class='col-xs-3'> Month<select class='span2  form-control' required name='from_month'><option value=''>Month</option><option value='Jan'>Jan</option>
                                          <option value='Feb'>Feb</option>
                                          <option value='March'>March</option>
                                          <option value='April'>April</option>
                                          <option value='May'>May</option>
                                          <option value='June'>June</option>
                                          <option value='July'>July</option>
                                          <option value='Aug'>Aug</option>
                                          <option value='Sept'>Sept</option>
                                          <option value='Oct'>Oct</option>
                                          <option value='Nov'>Nov</option>
                                          <option value='Dec'>Dec</option>
                                        </select>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class='col-xs-3'>
                                      Year
                                          <input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='year' name='from_year' required pattern='[0-9]{4,4}'>
                                      </div>
                                      <span class='box'>
                                      <div class='col-xs-3'>
                                      Month
                                        <select class='span2 form-control'  name='to_month' >
                                          <option value=''>Month</option>
                                          <option value='Jan'>Jan</option>
                                          <option value='Feb'>Feb</option>
                                          <option value='March' >March</option>
                                          <option value='April'>April</option>
                                          <option value='May'>May</option>
                                          <option value='June'>June</option>
                                          <option value='July'>July</option>
                                          <option value='Aug'>Aug</option>
                                          <option value='Sept'>Sept</option>
                                          <option value='Oct'>Oct</option>
                                          <option value='Nov'>Nov</option>
                                          <option value='Dec'>Dec</option>
                                        </select>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class='col-xs-3'>
                                      Year
                                         <input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='year' name='to_year'  >
                                      </div>
                                      </span>

                                      <div id='ab'></div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>

                               <div class='cl'></div>
                                <div class='form-group'>
                                  <label class='col-sm-4'>Degree / Course title*</label>
                                  <div class='col-sm-8'>
                                    <input type='text' class='form-control ' name='title' required />
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                   <div class='cl'></div>"
    });

    });

    $("#item").on("click",".delete", function(){
    $(this).closest(".form-group").remove();
    });
```

Comment: By "inverted commas" do you mean the single quote `'`?

Comment: Yes ,single quote  or double quote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a blackslash `\` at the end of each lines. Multiples lines string can't be parsed without it in js

EDIT : with example

```
$('#item').append("<div class='form-group'><label class='col-sm-4 '>Period</label><div class='col-sm-8'><div class='checkbox'><label><input type='checkbox' value='YES' name='currently_attending'>I`m currently attending this course</label></div><div class='row'><div class='col-xs-3'> Month<select class='span2  form-control' required name='from_month'><option value=''>Month</option><option value='Jan'>Jan</option> \
                                      <option value='Feb'>Feb</option> \
                                      <option value='March'>March</option> \
                                      <option value='April'>April</option> \
                                      <option value='May'>May</option>");
```

Comment: Can u You explain giving example